# Connect to JDBC python

Tags: python, jdbc, jaydebeapi

I am trying to connect to my GaussDB or even PostgreSQL using in python JayDeBeApi from linux, but I keep getting this error:

```
Error Class com.gauss.driver not found
```

I copy my jar file to `/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd46/lib/com.driver.jar`

is there something else ?

```
import jaydebeapi
import sys
 jaydebeapi.connect("com.gauss.Driver",
    url, [username, password], "./file-jdbc.jar")
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Copying random drivers into a Java installation will not automagically add them to the class path, and it is not something you should do. Why do you think that would work?

Comment: So what should I do please? I am not familiar with class path in linux

Answer (score 0):

You can try to explicitly start a JVM and pass it the fullpath of your driver jar file:

```py
import jaydebeapi
import jpype

jpype.startJVM(jpype.getDefaultJVMPath(),
                   f"-Djava.class.path=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd46/lib/com.driver.jar")


jaydebeapi.connect("com.gauss.Driver", url, [username, password], "/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd46/lib/")
```

If you're using postgresSQL databases I would also suggest you to take a look to the psycopg library:

https://pypi.org/project/psycopg/

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/introduction-to-psycopg2-module-in-python/